# Retrieve all records, where ALL related records are equal to string

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables.  One contains a list of projects, and the other contains a list of tasks in those projects.

I want to pull a list of only those projects where all tasks have a status of "Complete".

My data looks like this:

Projects Table:

```
ID,ProjectName,ProjectStatus
```

Tasks Table:

```
ID, ProjectID, TaskName, TaskStatus
```

`Tasks.ProjectID = Projects.ID`

I can do the basic select statement to get all records, and can filter where TaskStatus is a particular status, but again, I only want a list of Projects where ALL tasks are complete.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Now just to make sure: when you say ALL associated tasks are complete,  are you using the term in the conventional way, meaning all of its zero or more tasks are complete, or by some chance would you be requiring the project to have at least one task?  Normally a project with NO associated tasks would be something you want, but some people do use "all" in a funny, non-classical-logic way....

Comment: Thanks for asking on the clarification.  I did mean all.  I have created the application so that it creates an initial task when the project is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a NOT EXISTS subquery:

```
select * 
  from Projects P
 where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Tasks where Tasks.ProjectID = P.ID and TaskStatus <> 'COMPLETE')
```

**Edit to complete**

You can also use the NOT IN subquery:

```
select *
  from Projects
 where ID NOT IN (select ProjectID from Tasks where TaskStatus = 'COMPLETE')
```

Whether to use one or the other, it will depend on your table data volume and indexes:

The first option will run a subquery for each row of the parent query, but will access (if exists, probably yes) by a ProjectID index.

The second option will run the subquery first, only once, and then run the parent query using the subquery results. But the subquery probably won't use any index, since it's not likely to have an index on the TaskStatus field (it wouldn't make much sense).

But then again, if you don't have many rows on the Tasks table, then no index would be use in any case, since it'd be cheaper to just do a full scan of the table. So my recomendation is, check the execution plan, compare costs, and if possible run a few benchmarks to decide wich option works better for this, or any other case.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT ID, ProjectName            -- This query will select all projects where
FROM Projects                     -- ID is not on the list of the subquery
WHERE ID  NOT IN                                    
        ( SELECT ProjectID                    -- This subquery will get all
          FROM Tasks                          -- ProjectID who has INCOMPLETE
          WHERE TaskStatus <> 'COMPLETE')     -- taskStatus
```